# Getting application error: 2 in GAE PyDev application when deployed on app engine. Works fine locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pydev, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am getting

> DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')

I'm making an API call to an application deployed on Tomcat on my machine and expecting a XML response, but doesn't work. Can someone propose a solution or an alternate route?

I am working on an IT build laptop and suspected that that could be the issue so I tried from a laptop that is not behind firewall and not on company network, but that didnt' help either.

Code Snippet:

```
base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/recomendations/'
url = (base_url + 'api/1.0/otherusersalsoviewed?' + urlencode(args))
req = urlfetch.fetch(url, None, urlfetch.GET, {}, False, True, 60, False) 
if req.status_code==200:
   root = ElementTree(fromstring(req.content)).getroot()
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the errors you are seeing in your log?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the url you are specifying is pointing to localhost, which means 'this computer' (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), i.e. when you deploy your app to GAE localhost refer to GAE, which is meaningless.

Comment: Also, the port number is an issue here.

Comment: I have used my ip address in the deployed version. Still getting the same error!

Comment: @Christopher Ramirez.. Why is the port number an issue? In my deployed application i have used http://ipadress:8080/recommendations/  Isn't that ok?

Comment: Is your ip static? Try running the snippet with your IP address in http://shell.appspot.com/

Comment: ok.. So my ip is static and I did try my snippet in shell. I am getting a download error there as well :(

Comment: "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 365, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2

Comment: @user1481650 because production server does not use 8080 port. It uses 80 or 447 for SSL. Avoid using absolute URLs. Try instead `base_url = '/recomendations/'` which should work on development and production.

Comment: @Christopher Ramírez, as I understood user1481650 is trying to connect to another service, which is a Tomcat deployment.

Comment: @user1481650, I suggest you to edit your original post to include the error you are getting and to remove 'localhost' from your url.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I was geting:

```
ApplicationError: 2
```

I fixed removing references to [users.create_logout_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls)